# Merge "automount" and "automounting" tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I've noticed that both ["automount"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/automount/info) (no description, count=20) and ["automounting"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/automounting/info) (count=216) tags exist.

1. Can we merge these tags?  If not, how do we differentiate them?
2. If the answers to this question determine that they should be merged, how is this actioned? Do I flag for moderator intervention?

Comment: The tags have been merged.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think those should indeed be merged, yes. And this is precisely how to get it done: post on meta, see if everyone agrees and wait until the mods do their jobs.

So, unless anyone objects, I'll be merging them.